# How to use Mapstruct when target is inline object?

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have the object like this:

```
class User {

 private String firstName;

 private String secondName;

 private int age;

 ....
 get/set methods

}
```

And another object has User as a property:

```
class UserHolder {

 private User user;

 ....
 get/set methods

}
```

I want to convert UserHolder to User use [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/).

When I write this mapper I've something like this:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserHolderMapper {

 @Mapping(source = "user.firstName", target = "firstName")
 @Mapping(source = "user.secondName", target = "secondName")
 @Mapping(source = "user.age", target = "age")
 User toUser(UserHolder source);

}
```

But it contains a lot of boilerplate code (in @Mapping annotation), how I can say to mapper that I want to map **source.user** to **this target** without specifying fields of target?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently not possible. There is already a feature request [#1406](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1406) which is quite similar to what you need.

In any case as a workaround your mapper can look like:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserHolderMapper {

    default User toUser(UserHolder source) {
        return source == null ? null : toUser(source.getUser());
    }

    User toUser(UserDto source);
}
```

I don't know what the object in `UserHolder` is. `UserDto` is just a presumption, it can be any object.

In case you don't want to expose `User toUser(UserDto source)` then you can create an abstract mapper and make that method protected and abstract there. MapStruct will be able to handle it

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think it is the best way to do this and will hope that feature request will be resolved.

Comment: You should accept the answer if it answers the question

Answer (score 13):

I may be late to the party. However following should work fine.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserHolderMapper {

 @Mapping(source = "source.user", target = ".")
 User toUser(UserHolder source);

}
```

Comment: This produces a NPE in my setup.

Comment: This works at my end, thank you. Using dot makes this a complete object in generated code